# Does 'I took the trouble' have a negative cognotation?

Tags: idiom-meaning

Example phrase: When I became aware of IBM I took the trouble to learn more.

Does the idiom "I took the trouble" have a negative connotation in business writing?   Does it convey a thought of laziness or arrogance.

Update: Thanks for the points of view, as I cannot risk how it will be interpreted by the audience, I decided to be cautious and edit. Interesting enough the original owner is British.

When I became aware of IBM I took the initiative to learn more.

Comment: If someone says 'I took the trouble...' then (IMO as a UK-English speaker), they are usually pointing out how much trouble they went to, which the recipient either hasn't noticed or hasn't appreciated. The only time this would be used in business writing is when someone is irritated that their efforts haven't been recognised by the recipient - so it's a polite way of saying 'Hey - I did this and you haven't even noticed! I made quite an effort there, and you SHOULD have noticed'.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. It means that you make more effort than you normally would, which is positive. In your example, it means that the person dedicated time and effort to learn more about IBM.

It can have a negative meaning in a sentence like this:

'He never takes the trouble to phone his mother' - meaning that he doesn't bother himself to do it.